# Change the Display Order of a Full Calendar basicWeek view (day/month instead of month/day)

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to change the display order of the month/day. DAY/MONTH instead of MONTH/DAY.

BasicWeek View: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/basic-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `columnFormat` in the `View Option Hash`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
        defaultView: 'basicWeek',
        editable: true,
        columnFormat:{      // <===THERE       
            month: 'ddd',    
            week: 'ddd D/M', 
            day: 'dddd' 
        },
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/afd5fcpt/1/

Comment: I'm glad to help @MarceloAraujo...btw, disable directory listing on your Apache Server http://crosaratech.com.br/ ...cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize the [columnFormat](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/columnFormat/) and pass in a string.

It uses [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

e.g. `columnFormat: "D/M"`